# PHP SESSIONS insert user id into form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session

I have a system using php sessions - I want to capture and insert the user id into a submit form (to db). I am having problems making this work -

```
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('login.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

above is the session start

```
<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>
```

this is what i tried to use to insert - the form submit works fine and passes other fields to the db - but the user id is always blank -

Thanks -

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually setting `$_SESSION['userSession']` before trying to use it in your query. Or is it set somewhere else? Your code isn't clear.

Comment: Did you trying to put session in a variable before using in query and also using `bindParam` to set parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've posted, no data is actually getting added to the PHP session. You'll need to set it using the `$_SESSION` superglobal, along these lines, before you can grab it from the session:
`$_SESSION['user'] = $user_home`

Comment: thanks - do you mean add this to the session code (located at the top of the page)?

Comment: Well, you'll add the `USER` instance to the session after you've created it. Presumably, you'll also want to populate that object with some values beforehand

Comment: '$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['userID'] = $useid
?>'

i added this  ..... correct?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['useid'];?>"

and this for the form